# Excel VBA: If statement with shape fill (favourite button)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a favourite button, but the stage I'm on is trying to make the button have no fill and upon click have it show a fill. I have also set up a button to insert the star. Code below:

```
Sub favourite_btn()

Dim star_shp As Shape

Dim clLeft As Double
Dim clTop As Double
Dim clWidth As Double
Dim clHeight As Double


Set cl = Range("A1")


With star_shp
    clLeft = cl.Left
    clTop = cl.Top
    clWidth = 50
    clHeight = 50
End With

Set star_shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShape5pointStar, clLeft, clTop, clWidth, clHeight)

    With star_shp
        .Line.Visible = msoTrue
        '.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 16777215
    End With


End Sub
```

```
Sub star_fill()

Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("5-Point Star 7")
    Dim test As String

    Debug.Print shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB

    If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 16777215 Then 'if it is transparent
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 65535 'make it yellow
        test = ws3.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        MsgBox test
    Else
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 16777215 'otherwise back to transparent
    End If




End Sub
```

and I getting an error when I click on the star (which triggers the star_fill macro "the index into the specified collection is out of bounds" and it highlights the line `"Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(star_shp)"` in the star_Fill sub. I thought it was because I hadn't set the star_shp variable as a public variable but I did that and it still throws this error.

Any ideas? Would appreciate any help! Thanks

EDIT: Updated my code to reflect the changes as suggested in the comments below. Currently I'm trying to not refer to the Star shape by it's specific name and instead refer to it by it's variable as defined in the first subroutine. So my question is around how to make a variable a global variable so a different subroutine can refer to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated code** - toggle between yellow and transparent fill:

```
Sub star_fill()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("5-Point Star 4")

    Debug.Print shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB

    If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 16777215 Then 'if it is transparent
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 65535 'make it yellow
    Else
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 16777215 'otherwise back to transparent
    End If
End Sub
```

**Update #2:**

Public variable will only work if you specify it outside of your `Sub` routine (the variable value always lives and dies within a given routine, if embedded within the routine). So you would need to do do the following:

```
Public star_shp as Shape

Sub favourite_btn()
...
```

However, Public variable approach is not error-proof because it could also lose its reference to the shape (for example, closing and opening the file).

An alternative would be to have a routine to create the shape (like your `favourite_btn` sub) and a completely separate routine to dictate the shapes' behavior. The example below will work for any shape created by your routine and even if your routine is used to create multiple (different) shapes.

Note the use of:

- `.OnAction = "star_fill"` which assigns your star_fill subroutine to a created shape.
- `Application.Caller` which is used to bind user's selected shape to the subroutine `star_fill`. Thanks to this line we are no longer in need of creating a Public Variable `star_shp`.

```vb
    Sub favourite_btn()
        Dim star_shp    As Shape
        Dim clLeft      As Double
        Dim clTop       As Double
        Dim clWidth     As Double
        Dim clHeight    As Double
        Dim cl          As Range

        Set cl = Range("A1")

        Set star_shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShape5pointStar, cl.Left, cl.Top, 50, 50)

        With star_shp
            .Line.Visible = msoTrue
            '.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 16777215
            .OnAction = "star_fill"
        End With

    End Sub

    Sub star_fill()
        Dim star_shp    As Shape

        On Error Resume Next
            Set star_shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not star_shp Is Nothing Then
            If star_shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 16777215 Then 'if it is transparent
                star_shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 65535 'make it yellow
            Else
                star_shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 16777215 'otherwise back to transparent
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You can call that with a name?! Wow.

Comment: So I replaced my sub with yours and replaced 5-point Star 4 with 5-point Star 6 as that's the name of the shape on my spreadsheet and it doesn't throw back an error but when I click the star it doesn't do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 trust me I was also surprised, I just found it today!

Comment: @Sam good news, we're almost there. Could you please clarify what your `If` statement should do? I see that in the first case if `shp.Fill.Visible` is False, then you want to change the fill colour to yellow. However, I think that you won't be able to change the fill colour as long as `shp.Fill.Visible` is set to True. So you'd need to add `shp.Fill.Visible = msoCTrue` before your `If` statement.

Comment: So the first subroutine (favourite_btn) should add an unfilled star with an outline. Then if the star is clicked it triggers a subroutine (star_fill) that will fill the star in with yellow, and then if it is clicked again it needs to go back to being unfilled. Eventually when it is filled in (aka favourite is enabled for the user) it will take the values from that row and place them in another sheet. It's a way for people to favourite row's of data that are used often - thanks for your help!

Comment: Ahh got ya, thanks for an update. I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise you had updated the code already, I've tried it and still getting the same result where you click it and it doesn't do anything (but doesn't return an error) EDIT: Ah I got it to work, I realised that the Star on the sheet was the original which had no fill as opposed to your RGB transparent code. So I added a new star using your code and then tried the star_fill code and it worked! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: My only remaining question is where it refers to "5-Point Star 4", how can I make that refer to star_shp variable from the other subroutine (favourite_btn) because I plan on having multiple star shapes next to multiple rows EDIT: As you can see in the other comment thread below, I tried adding Public before the setting of the shape variable, hoping it would make it a global variable, but it didn't work. EDIT2: I've updated my original question with the new code in case it's needed

Comment: @Sam fair question. I'm on my way back home but I'll think about it and reply later today.

Comment: @Sam I just updated my answer - give it a try and let me know if anything is unclear. Take care.

Comment: Works perfectly. I don't know why I didn't think of application caller as I've used it elsewhere in this spreadsheet. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveSheet.shapes` accepts a number as input, and finds the nth shape. You already have your shape (`star_shp`), so there's no need to try to get it again!

If you don't already have it, however, you'll need to find it by iterating through all shapes in the active sheet looking for `star_shp`. I recommend tagging it somehow with a persistent identifier (naming it, perhaps?) and looking for that, but make sure you test what happens when the user copies it.

```
Dim shp As Shape

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.shapes
    If shp.name = "sparklesthethird" Then
        Msgbox("found it")
        Exit For
    Endif
Next
```

Comment: I tried `Set shp = star_shp` but its coming back with Object required (I've edited my original post code with that new line too)

Comment: @Sam I just realised that that was inside a subroutine. I don't think public does what you want, so I suggest removing it. I haven't used VBA for over a year,  but its horror is sadly burned onto my memory. Try this.

Comment: Try what? Did you mean try removing the Public? Just tried that and it still throws back an Object required unfortunately - I was using Public as I thought it meant that variable was global so I could refer to it in another Sub

Comment: Also, that's not how subroutines work. You're thinking of global variables, but I'm pretty sure those aren't saved with the workbook. I sincerely, sincerely hope that's not how subroutines work in VBA.

Comment: Edited my original post with updated code, still Object Required. I think it has to be something to do with using a variable that isn't inside the same subroutine

Comment: Remove the faulty line, since you're immediately overwriting the variable's value anyway, and add a name check or something.